# How to I get light to not affect the rest of the scene

Tags: lighting

I made a test of a idea I had and I had a problem with the lighting of the scene

So I have a reflective face shield of a astronaut and way off there's an object(the orang band) that has an emitter node. The space/stars thing is a hdri, how to I make the orange light of the band not effect anything else(ie the backround cause its really red)
[image: The render of the astronaut]

Answer (score 0):

This is - as far as i know - not really possible at the moment. The feature is called "light linking" https://developer.blender.org/T68915

1. In Eevee you could try to work with light -> custom distance
2. Or work with layers, meaning to seperate your renders per object/ fore-/background and combining them again in the compositor.

Comment: Is there any way to make the orange band give off light other than a node?

Comment: for clarification: are you rendering in eevee or in cycles? Is the orange-emissive-band a material emission? A. Eevee material emission has the kind of behaviour your want, not as e feature but as its limited to lamp type based illumination and not material based. B. Even in Cycles you could render the emission pass seperate and get the bloom effect via postprocessing in the compositor.